# Prove that the union of sequentially compact spaces is sequentially compact

Tags: metric-spaces

I'm teaching myself metric spaces, and was wondering how to do this.

I have tried starting with two sequentially compact spaces (A and B) and then proving the general finite case using induction. Since we've defined sequentially compact as a metric space where any sequence has a convergent subsequence, I've tried to split into cases and consider when happens at the tail of the sequence, but am not having much success.

Comment: First, look for a subsequence than lies entirely in one of the two spaces.

Comment: And remember that a subsequence of a subsequence is also a subsequence of the original sequence.

Comment: Are you referring to a finite union?

Comment: @רוירז Yes, a finite union

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks! What would my cases be then?